"He usually goes to school on time" or "He goes to school usually on time."
Which is the correct Sentence?

a) "He usually goes to school on time"

or

b) "He goes to school usually on time."


(a) is by far the more natural. Someone might use (b) to emphasise the phrase 'usually on time', but in written English it needs punctuation to show this; "He goes to school - usually on time."

(a) might look to a non-native speaker like it's saying "He usually goes to school on time but sometimes he doesn't go to school (at any time)", but I think most native speakers would assume it means "He usually goes to school on time but sometimes he doesn't go to school on time." Intonation in spoken English helps clarify meanings.


a) "He usually goes to school on time"

"Usually" modifies "goes"
or
b) "He goes to school, usually on time."
This needs the comma, which I have added.
"usually on time" is an after-thought. It is a free modifier or sentence adverb, which modifies the whole of the main clause, which is "He goes to school".

Is this correct? See the comments for the OP. To me, 'usually' modifies the whole clause, so the implied alternative is 'occasionally he goes to school late'. If you are right the alternative would be 'occasionally he doesn't go to school at all', but I don't think we read it this way.

This is definitely the right answer. The comma (or hyphen as Kate uses) in the second phrase is necessary as stated. The main statement stands alone with the comma standing for a spoken pause.
